# UWP start application in maximize view and show minimize and close button

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml, titlebar

I want to start my UWP application in maximize view showing the title bar with a close button and minimize button. I have added the below code in the OnLaunched method in App.xaml.cs.

```
 protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
       
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }
        mDispatcher = rootFrame.Dispatcher;

        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode=ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;       
     }
```

My application launched in full-screen mode but it doesn't initially show the title bar. It shows the title bar only if I hover over the upper end of the application. How can I enable to show the title bar all the time without hovering over the top, at the app launch?

Comment: Can using `ApplicationViewWindowingMode.Maximized` meets your needs? The close button and minimize button will be displayed normally, but the taskbar will be displayed below the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

To start your UWP application in maximized view with the title bar and close/minimize buttons, you can modify the OnLaunched method in the App.xaml.cs file as follows:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create and activate the main window
        var mainWindow = new MainPage();
        Window.Current.Content = mainWindow;
        Window.Current.Activate();

        //Get the current ApplicationView to modify the title bar and window display settings.
        var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

        //Optionally, enter full-screen mode by calling TryEnterFullScreenMode()
        //if you want to start the application in full-screen.
        view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();

        //Set the ButtonBackgroundColor and ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor properties
        //of the TitleBar to Colors.Transparent to make the buttons blend with the title bar.
        view.TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        view.TitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;

        //Set the FullScreenSystemOverlayMode to FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Standard
        //to show the title bar. Ensure that the window is maximized
        //and set the window size and display mode
        view.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Standard;

        //Use TryResizeView() to set the desired initial window size.
        //Adjust the Size object parameter according to your requirements.
        view.TryResizeView(new Size(800, 600));
    }
```